# Step function trigger

Tags: voltage

I want to design a circuit that has one input and one output.
The output is originally at 0V.
The input is originally at 0V also. If the input increases and at the moment it reaches 0.2V, the output will have a step function changing from 0V to 1V.
How do I build this circuit?

Comment: a relay that activates at 200 mV ... connect the contacts to a 1 V power supply

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about the application and specific requirements such as output load, what "at the moment means" (within 10 milliseconds? within 10 nanoseconds?) and the accuracy requirements of the specified input and output voltages with the load connected to the output.

Comment: Search for "non-inverting Schmitt trigger".

Comment: Activation caused by a voltage growing over a preset treshold is quite common sub-function needed to make electronic circuits to work. A single computer uses it in billions of places. But the usable realization depends on exact requirements of tolerance, speed, noise immunity, available supply voltage, power limitations, capability to drive a load etc, etc, etc... As already said by others, reveal something of the wanted final application. Otherwise nearly any answer would be perfect for the question, but probably fully useless for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using an opamp or a comparator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4l0cZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V3 is your opamps power supply.
Make sure your opamp is capable of a rail-to-rail output to take advantage of the full voltage range.

V2 is your reference voltage connected to the negative input terminal.
If you don't have 0.2V available you can generate this using a simple resistor divider.

V1 is your ramping signal.
In this case demonstrated by a sawtooth ramping from 0V to 1V.

The opamp compares the voltage at the positive input with the one at the negative one.
If The voltage at the positive input is less than the negative input, then the output is low.
If The voltage at the positive input is above that of the negative input, then the output is high.

The edge case of the inputs being the same can be overcome by implementing a [schmitt trigger configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger) or by using a comparator with a built in schmitt trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposed solution. An OpAmp with Schmitt Trigger configuration. Another OpAmp for accurate output to 1 Volt.  The input diodes protect the OpAmp FET input. With a 1/4W R2 the maximum safe voltage input is about 120 Volts AC or DC. The output current capability is limited by the OpAmp and can be raised with another amplifier configuration using output power transistors, if necessary.

The amplifier will output 1 Volt when the input reaches 200mV. Then the input voltage return back to 10mV the output will return to zero volt.

[image: Amplifier with Schmitt Trigger]